# How to integrate the google + with ios and android native apps?

Tags: android, iphone

Please give some suggestion ? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Actullay, I am planning to integrate the  google+. Before starting, I want to get suggestion. So Now , I am going to explore about the https://developers.google.com/+/api/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

refer the google plus api

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: Hi .. they provided the API in alpha right ? shall I start to use those?